# Android bluetooth socket read timeout error

Tags: android, sockets, printing, bluetooth

We are trying to print a receipt using Android bluetooth printer using custom app but the following bit of code gives bluetooth socket read timeout error.

```
  try {
            if (mmDevice != null) {
                // Standard SerialPortService ID
                UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
                mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                mmSocket.connect();
                mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

                beginListenForData();

                //   myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The analogics 2 inch printer connects successfully but NGX printer throwing the above exception. The android version is 6.0

**EDIT:** Now we changed the `mmSocket` creation line to

`mmSocket = mmDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);` and socket is creating sussessfully but the printer not writing the output at   `String msg = "Test"; mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());`